Saber si una celda es mayor en X cantidad a otra
Saber si una celda es mayor que otra es algo fácil. Pero es posible saber si una celda es mayor o supera a otra en X cantidad?? Les explico mejor...
Tengo dos columnas de datos



PVP Proveedor (G)
PVP Tienda (H)




33
35


69
99


29
35



Lo que quier hacer es darle formato (algo básico, color de fondo y fondo negrita) al PVP Tienda pero solo si este supera en unos 10 o X cantidad al PVP Proveedor.
En el ejemplo anterior el 99 sale diferente (con formato) porque supera en más de 10 al 69.
Ya tengo una formula para hacer lo contrario, la cual me formatea el PVP Proveedor si este supera al PVP Tienda y lo hago con formatos condicionales así

=$G3>$H3

Y se aplica a

=$G$3:$G$999

Esto lo que hace es que en toda la hoja le da formato a los PVP Proveedor que son mayores que el PVP Tienda y me permite cambiarlos rápidamente (para no perder ganancias obviamente) pero tengo la necesidad de ver si un PVP Tienda tiene demasiado elevado su precio de venta con respecto al de mi proveedor y por eso necesito hacer lo que acá he explicado.
Estaba pensando ("según mi lógica") en algo como

SI(SI($G>$H)>10;formato;"")

Pero claro, ese segundo IF >10 no existe ni es un comparador de Excel. En palabras mortales la formula sería: Si $G es mayor en 10 a $H dale este formato
PDs: Ustedes saben que ya he intentado mucho antes de solicitar ayuda acá. El ejemplo que pongo es para que vean que si tengo una parte resuelta y que no me manden hacer el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable porque ni idea de que formula usar.
Si es necesario hacerlo con alguna macro o vb podría intentarlo pero la verdad nunca he tocado el vb de Excel.
El PVP es el Precio de Venta al Publico, es decir, el precio de venta de un producto.

=NOT((A1+10)>B1)

tambien vale (A1-B1) > 10...

Debo aclarar que anoche probé el comentario de @alanfcm y me sirvió correctamente, lo implemente con $ en las celdas para que se ejecute en toda la hoja y quedó muy bien. Igual la respuesta de jachguate es excelente, a ambos ya les dí upvote

El secreto está en como se redacta la condición.
Si en lenguaje coloquial dices que quieres resaltar los precios de tienda que sea mayores al precio del proveedor más 10, la fórmula cae por su propio peso, por ejemplo, puedes usar:
=$H2>($G2+10)

Lo que dará este resultado:

Si en lenguaje coloquial dices que quieres resaltar los precios de tienda cuya diferencia con el precio del proveedor sea mayor a 10, puedes usar:
=$H2-$G2>10

Que produce el mismo resultado visual:


Es increíble, probé con un montón de cosas y sin embargo era de darle la vuelta a la formula y ver si el PVP de Tienda era mayor al PVP del Proveedor + 10  Me siendo mal hasta por haber preguntado

Todo se aprende, seguro la próxima vas a tener más recursos para darle la vuelta, y seguro algún día te vuelves a topar con otra que va a requerir de una vuelta de tuerca más y probablemente vuelvas a preguntar otra vez. Lo importante es ir mejorando las herramientas dentro de nuestra caja.
